# Как спарсить эту страницу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bs4

Подскажите пожалуйста, как спарсить эту страницу: https://www.re-store.ru/catalog/MYD82RU-A/.
Мой парсер в теге body вместо кода html выводит js скрипты.
Код парсера:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.re-store.ru/catalog/MYD82RU-A/'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)



soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")



print(soup)
```

И еще, можно ли парсить комментарии?

Comment: `bs4` парсер html/xml, а для работы с js нужен движок на js. Используйте selenium

Comment: это html страница, но почему-то при парсинге выдает js скрипты

Comment: В html хранится: html, js, css, base64 (часто для хранения картинок), svg (иконки). Когда вы такую страницу откроете браузером он выполнит js код и добавятся данные в html

Answer (score 2):

В таких ситуациях (когда страница в `Просмотреть код страницы` отличается от того, что выводит `python`) лучше использовать `selenium`, как и подсказал `gil9red`. Он сымитирует ваш браузер. Подобный код я применял в своем проекте.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = r'https://www.re-store.ru/catalog/MYD82RU-A/'


def get_html_new(url=None):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(str(url))
    html = browser.page_source
    time.sleep(2)
    return html


html = get_html_new(url=url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
teg = soup.find("body")
print(teg)
```

Comment: Ваш код выдает ошибку: